# running VisualStudio CF3.5 apps on WINCE

Tags: .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am trying to write a program for a chinese PNA device with wince 5.0.
But everytime I write a simple program in VS8 with C# and 'deploy' it to my device it just doesn't run. First it complains about disposing an object call menu, although I don't want an menu but VS8 just creates one for me. If I delete the menu from the form the program gives an exception. I installed a program call MIOPocket on the PNA with has powertoys some games and MS media player. It also creates a directory .net framework 3.5  so I known 3.5 is installed and must be working. But I think I am missing something.
I am also not sure what to choice as target device ; windows mobile or WINCE.
If I click the .exe file under win7 it works but under wince its a no go.

Maybe someone has a clue what is going wrong ?

Comment: Does the program work on an emulator?

Comment: Yes strangely it works on an emulator (windows mobile 5 emulator).
The program now only consist of form1 so I don't think the program is wrong. Maybe the target device is wrong ?
In visual studio I can choice between wince, pocketpc, windows mobile 5 and 6. But because I don't use 'unmanged' code I wouldn't expect that the target makes any difference.
Its the first prog. I ever wrote for a wince device and I think I do something very stupidly wrong but I can't find out what it is.
The only thing I get now is an 0xC0000005 exception

Comment: I compiled it now in debug and when I move the exception dialog away I can see that the framework of Form1 is drawn (with close  and min/max buttons) but right after that it crashes

Comment: What's the exception you get without the menu?

Comment: Without the menu I get the 0C0000005 exception with the menu I get a object disposed message. I looked at the CF3.5 directory and saw a .net2.0 sample exe file, double clicked that and it worked !
So I compiled my program in CF2.0 and that worked also.
Now I known for sure that CF3.5 is not installed correctly.

Comment: But when I try to install (or repair) CF3.5 it doesn't work, I got an error almost at the end of installation that there is not enough memory. I selected more program memory in wince but that didn't help. Strangly if I look at the install logging the install doesn't complain about diskspace or low memory but complains that the device is not compatible with a filename  with mobile in its name.
I selected the wince.armv4 cab file and not the wm.armv4 cab file when I tried to install it manually but got the same error.
Anyhow it works now but only CF2.0 ;(

Answer (score 0):

One point here: Windows CE and Windows Mobile are not the same platform at all really.

I do not think windows mobile is the right platform to target for a 'PNA' (personal navigation assistant?), so I would start with making sure the project - from it's very beginning, from it's creation in VS - is targeted for windows CE. I have not had much success trying to convert Windows Mobile projects to Windows CE ones (even by notepad-level changes to the csprj file).

The menu is a result of it being a windows mobile project, the standard on a WinMo device being a softbutton menu or two displayed on the bottom of the screen. The menu being tied to the softbutton key press stuff ... specific to WinMo. Also: some of the libraries it might expect linked for GSM stuff would probably engender all sorts of problems.

Aidanapword